# How to display help for custom property in toolbox of visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i have a custom control in c# in which i define two properties vertical align and horizontal align,
now i want to display help in editor when user set this property like textbox's textalignment property setting.
in help i want to display  following options:

**Left**

**Center**

**Middle**

like combobox help how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

You may provide summary for the Property like

```
/// <summary>
/// Horizontal Alignment : Left, Middle, Right
/// </summary>
public int HorizontalAlign { get; set; }
```

Now when you access this property in any class and hover over Horizontal Align in the editor the summary will show

The shortcut for summary tag generation is "///" (like a snippet)

When you type this above the property it generates the tag automatically and you can provide the description.